# Create a scope for temporary variables in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I searched around but I did not found the answer to this question.

Is there any aesthetic, pythonic way to create temporary variables in an arbitrary scope so I am sure they won't ever appear outside this scope ?

For exemple in OCaml, I can write :

```
let x = 3 and y = 5 in z = x + y
```

I'd love to do some stuff like this in Python. For exemple, let's imagine I create a module `talker.py` with a lot of useful functions, and each of them uses a variable that I don't want to copy again and again.

```
# talker.py

sentance = ( 'Has provinciae has dictione emergunt sorte aptae'
  'iuris navigerum nusquam iuris in natura sorte aptae visitur'
  'in verum dictione flumen.' )

def talk() :
  print sentance

def talk_loudly() :
  print sentance.upper()

def any_other_useful_function :
  # do stuff using sentance
```

Then I want to use all of these wonderful functions in another file, but :

- I want to import all these functions at once (without naming each of them)
- I **don't want** to have access to `sentance` : this variable has done it's job, now I want it to fall in darkness and to be forgotten.

But if I call this module with `import talk` or `from talk import *`, this second condition won't be respected.

This is an example of where I could use a "special scope for temporary variables", even if it is not the only situation in which I wish I had this at range.

I thought about using the `with ... :` statement but I wasn't satisfied with the result.

Any idea is welcomed, but I am looking for the most aesthetic and least wordy manner to proceed.

Comment: Object orient your whole program, Don't stick to non OO methodology

Comment: @sameerasy Doing so, I'd have to keep a `talker_instance.*` syntax everywhere whereas I prefer to see it as a repertory of utility functions I want to have access everywhere in the program as if I wrote them just above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the `__all__` name on your module, to control the names which will be available when you are using `from talk import *`.

[Documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: Is there anyway to tweak this solution in order to have the same behaviour with `import talker` (_i.e._ `talker.talk()` is recognized but not `talker.sentance`) ?

Comment: No, not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `sentance` isn't temporary. Those functions are relying on its existence. You could `del sentance` and it would be gone but the functions would throw an error.

A common Python convention is to prefix the name with an underscore. This signals that the variable is 'protected'. It doesn't do anything, but programmers know that they probably shouldn't access it from outside the module (or class).

Comment: Note:  a leading underscore will also prevent it from getting collected by `import *`, without needing to specify that explicitly using `__all__`